# Error: [mobx] Computed values are not allowed to cause side effects by changing observables that are already being observed. Tried to modify:

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, mobx

I'm trying to add and remove upload gifs for a filtering event

Where did I fail?

```
    @observable loading = false; //Loading variable being tracked in component
    @computed get filtered() {
    this.loading=true;//true
    let filteredList = this.list.filter(
      item => item.data.some(
        obj => obj.tr_x.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterTermValue)
      )
    );
    this.loading=false;//false
    if (filteredList.length)
      return filteredList;
    return this.list;
  }
```

Comment: You are not allowed to change observable variables inside the body of computed function.

Answer (score 0):

What is a `@computed` decoration?

It is a kind of cache. If the arguments does not change, do not compute, just return the previous computed value.

So as good practice to avoid side effects those `@computed` functions can not change anything, just compute idempotent information.

And you need to look to your stack call to ensure the code that change any property are not called by a `@computed` function.